# What can you do with thesixtyone reputations?

Tags: music

In http://thesixtyone.com you earn reputation points if songs "hearted" by you are also "hearted" by other people. My question is what can you do with these points?

Answer (score 2):

From [the FAQ](http://old.thesixtyone.com/faq/):

> **What are levels?**
>
> Levels represent your skill or experience in choosing good music on thesixtyone. Leveling up unlocks bonus features like the ability to heart a song more than once.
>
> **What do I get for each level?**
>
> For each level, you can give one more heart per song (past level five) and are given one additional heart to spend per day. The "revive" ability unlocks at level 10. More to come!

Comment: Ok..so thats it!